# can not create multiple instances of custom canvas view and can not pass input value to canvas functions -Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-canvas

I am having an issue i can not create multiple intances of my Custom Ui in multiple places. and can not send inputs to Mycanvas for further UI modification.

**MyCanvas class :**

```
public class MyCanvas extends View {
     private int total;
     private int width;
     private int height;

     @Override
     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        // Drawing my stuff here with (width and height gives me 0 here)
        if(total == 50 || total == 150){ total == 100;}
    }
     public int addToCanvas(int value){ total += value ;}
     public int subtractToCanvas(int value){ total -= value ;}

     //All three of contructors here
     public MyCanvas(Context context) {
       super(context);
       total = 100;
       width = getWidth();
       height = getHeight();
     }

     public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        total = 100;
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();
     }

    public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       total = 100;
       width = getWidth();
       height = getHeight();
    }
}
```

**Main Activity Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MyCanvas mycanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mycanvas= (MyCanvas) findViewById(R.id.customcanvas);
        mycanvas.addToCanvas(10);
    }
}
```

**Main Activity XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >  

    <Button android:id="@+id/bTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />    

    <com.example.me.MyCanvas android:id="@+id/customcanvas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

all i want is to use my default canvas in multiple places with different instances like Progress bar does..

Comment: what is  'addToCanvas()' supposed to do?

Comment: Could you explain where you want to have the other instances of your MyCanvas class? And what does int total represent? It doesn't seem to have any functionality

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to keep you from using that custom view in multiple places. Go ahead and instantiate one or two new ones :) But as of now I can't see that you are trying to change anything about your single custom View with respect to the UI.

Comment: actually i am making a bar filled with the value i give to it. like 10% i need the bar to filled.

Comment: added more detail to my question now its clear , i have debugged i can not get width and height in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be you tried too early to get information about the dimensions of your View. As far as I know the best time is in the 'onDraw()' method by calling 'getMeasuredHeight()' respectively 'getMeasuredWidth()'.

**EDIT**:

Just to have a working sample, I changed 'MyCanvas' by adding a Paint and a method for initializing it as well as some code in the 'onDraw()' method.

```
public class MyCanvas extends View
{
private int total;
private int width;
private int height;

private Paint paintLine;

public void init()
{
    // call this from all of the constructors
    paintLine = new Paint();
    paintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // linie
    paintLine.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 40, 80));
    paintLine.setStrokeWidth(2.0f); // strichbreite
    paintLine.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    // Drawing my stuff here with (width and height gives me 0 here)

    // use 'getMeasuredWidth()' and 'getMeasuredHeight()' here!
    // calling 'getWidth()' and 'getHeight()' in the constructor is too early,
    // the View is not yet laid out.
    width = getMeasuredWidth();
    height = getMeasuredHeight();

    canvas.drawCircle(width/2.0f, height/2.0f, (total / 100f) * (width + height)/8.0f, paintLine);

    // this won't compile:
    //if(total == 50 || total == 150){ total == 100;}
    if(total == 50 || total == 150){ total = 100;}
}


public int addToCanvas(int value)
{ total += value ;
    // you need to return something!
    return total;
}
public int subtractToCanvas(int value)
{ total -= value ;
    // same here
    return total;
}

//All three of contructors here
public MyCanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);
    total = 100;
//    width = getWidth();
//    height = getHeight();
    init();
}

public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    total = 100;
//    width = getWidth();
//    height = getHeight();
    init();
}

public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    total = 100;
 //   width = getWidth();
 //   height = getHeight();
    init();
}
}
```

The MainActivity, changed for test driving purposes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private MyCanvas mycanvas;
private Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bTest);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mycanvas.addToCanvas(10);
            mycanvas.invalidate();
        }
    });
    mycanvas= (MyCanvas) findViewById(R.id.customcanvas);
    mycanvas.addToCanvas(10);
}
}
```

Comment: Can i initialize width and height just for once?

Comment: @Fazal - how about setting the values in the layout file? I was wondering wether you really wanted them to be "wrap_content" (what content?), and while testing in Android Studio the custom view covered the whole screen. So, yes, I think you should use some dp values.

Comment: @Fazal - dp values are kind of independent of screen size (good for being able to develop for different devices) whereas 'getMeasured...()' will give you real pixels.

Comment: how can i use dp values in canvas.drawArc?

Comment: @Fazal - I think we have a misunderstanding here. First you use dp in the xml layout file to allocate space on the screen for the custom View. This is like a relative value. The System looks at the layout and the device and decides how many pixels your View will get. Then in the 'onDraw()' method, it's pixels all the time. You can use a boolean like 'firstDraw' to check wether this is indeed the first time the View has to draw itself and then getMeasured...() values (and they are already pixel values). Use these values to calculate the size in pixels of everything you want to draw.

Comment: Thank you so much . I wanted to get the width and height just for the first time the view has been created . i got that by using firstDraw method. and secondly i have changed that later wrap_content to match the parent. all i wanted to use dps in canvas which is now i know i can not. Many Thanks. My problem is being solved now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call mycanvas.invalidate() to redraw, after changed the value of "total".

Comment: i have tried my total variable remains the 0 . it could not initialize on the constructor